# Since DSC is deprecated, is there any other DataStax product that is a "community edition"?

Tags: cassandra

We want to downgrade our current datastax version from DSE version: 6.8.11 to a community edition as we are deprecating the environment

As far as i know, DSC version is deprecated, could you please confirm? Is there any other datastax product to be used as a cassandra community edition? Or should we migrate to Apache Cassandra?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

DataStax Community Edition (DSC) is a free, packaged version of open-source Apache Cassandra certified by DataStax for production use. For all intents and purposes, it is identical to open-source Cassandra but the package was tested, certified and distributed by DataStax.

The first DSC release for C* 1.1 was back in 2013. DataStax last released DSC with C* 3.0.9 in 2017 so it hasn't been supported for over 5 years.

The alternative is to deploy the open-source version of Apache Cassandra and purchase support separately like a [DataStax Luna](https://www.datastax.com/products/luna) subscription if you want.

For full disclosure: I work at DataStax. Cheers!